# Amazon SP API print item label

Tags: inbound, fba

We are trying to create FBA shipment. We create ShipmentId and did placements for items. and we can print shipment label with getlabels type. But how can we print item labels? I couldn't see any documentation to get item labels?

Thank you in advance for your help

We tried all FBA Inbound types